# DLL unloading procedure

Tags: c++, dll

I did solve my immediate problem at hand, but now I need to understand why it is solved. ;-)

So here I have couple more questions.

Suppose I have a class that is being exported from the DLL. Now this DLL should be loaded into the memory every time I call:

```
MyExportedClass *pb = new MyExportedClass;
```

and it should stay in memory and becomes unloaded only when I call:

```
delete pb;
```

Is this correct?

If I understood this correctly and the answer to the previous question is yes, then what should happen in the following scenario:

I have an interface which exported from the dll (dll1) and I have its implementation which is exported from another dll (dll2). So every time I execute:

```
MyInterface *pInterface = new MyImplementation;
```

both those dlls should be loaded in memory and they should stay in memory until I call:

```
delete pInterface;
```

Is this correct?

Now, if the answer to this question is yes - do I have a control/saying, which library will be unloaded first and which one will be second? Or the unload will always happen right after calling destructor of the appropriate class?

Now, is there a tool which checks if the library becomes unloaded and at which point? I can probably just use the fake DllMain() and check its process_detach case, but my impression always was: use DllMain when the library exports function and don't use DllMain when the library exports classes. I used this approach since MSVC 5/6 (following one of the books about C++).

Was I wrong and I can still use DLLMain in both cases?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that every instantation/destruction of an object does the same for the whole DLL?

Comment: My understanding of operating systems says that a DLL is only unloaded from memory when the memory is needed (by another DLL, program, etc.).  Deleting an object does not force the unloading of a DLL.

Comment: @deviantfan, not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, but then when the DLL becomes unloaded we will have a dangling pointer, right? I mean the object can be calling the function, but without the dll being present it will just crash. That is unless I'm missing something and the dll will load itself by OS in this case.

Comment: Also, a DLL is loaded into memory if it is not already in memory and a executable is calling a function in the DLL.

Comment: @Igor: you need to differentiate functions from variables.  A pointer to a class is different than a pointer to a function (or executable code).  Instantiating a class does nothing for the executable code; except that when the method or function is called, the OS must load the function into the memory, as necessary.  The function could reside in a DLL or in a part of the executable that isn't loaded.

Comment: Functions are not instantiated when a class is instantiated.  Functions are instantiated when they are invoked.  A structure can have data members that are used, but the functions are infrequently accessed.  Thus the members occupy memory, but the functions may not be loaded.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I understand that. What I am after is at which point the dll becomes unloaded. My understanding is that the dll should stay in memory for the lifetime of the pointer. Am I wrong?

Comment: `not sure what you mean` I mean that the answer for your first `Is this correct?` in the question is `No`. And the rest makes no sense anymore because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLL loading can be automatic (if listed in the import table) or manual (using `LoadLibrary`).  Some managed frameworks, like .NET, will silently call `LoadLibrary` for you when they see a DLL import declaration in their metadata, but C++ is not one of these.  The closest thing C++ has is delay-loading, where the function that calls `LoadLibrary` is (by default, you can substitute your own) provided by the compiler.

On the other hand, DLL unloading is always manual.  Deleting an object never implicitly unloads a DLL.  You have to call `FreeLibrary` (or `FreeLibraryAndExitThread`).  And you had better not call `FreeLibrary` while objects defined in that library are still in use.

Now, the COM system in Windows is a bit more complicated, because it manages DLL lifetime for you.  But DLL lifetime is still not controlled by object deletion, rather by calling a `DllCanUnloadNow` function in the DLL.  Usually you need to maintain a count of active objects in order to write that function correctly.  But it still requires your manual implementation, and you can simply always return false to never unload (this is a bit of a pain during development because you have to close the entire application to try a new plugin version, etc... but actually freeing every usage of a DLL and successfully unloading it is rare anyway)

And certainly there is nothing that will automatically unload a DLL listed in the import table, those get loaded during process startup and never unloaded, no matter how many object instances are created or destroyed.

Comment: do I have to call FreeLibrary{AndExitThread}()? What happens if I don't? Will OS take care of that? Remember I'm not exporting the function where I call the function and forget about the library - I'm exporting a C++ class which is instantiated by pointer. So, if I don't unload the dll, what happens? Will OS take care of that seeing that no one references the dll? AFAIU, this is a module handle that will not be freed, so it will be a resource leak, right?

Comment: @Igor: When the process exits, its DLLs get freed by the OS.  Unless you cause `FreeLibrary` to be called, the DLL stays in memory for as long as the process lives.  You can consider that a resource leak, but it is only once, no matter how many class instances and functions from the DLL you use, so it's not significant.  When people talk about memory leak bugs, they're talking about leaks happening each time an operation runs and accumulating over time.

Comment: thanx for an explanation.